# Count each Text value in XML using HADOOP mapreduce pgm

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop. I need to parse a small xml file using mapreduce program in java. I am using hadoop 1.0.4
say my xml file is

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>adv</name>
 <value>a</value>
 <dup>school</dup>
</property>
<property>
 <name>aghy</name>
 <value>a</value>
 <dup>bk</dup>
</property>
</configuration>
```

i need an output like this
adv 1  a 2  aghy 1 school 1 bk 1

how can i edit the code https://github.com/studhadoop/xmlparsing-hadoop/blob/master/XmlParser11.java .Any working idea.
pls help me out.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: so far i tried the pi estimator and wordcount.java examples   in http://cloudcelebrity.wordpress.com/2011/12/31/hadoop-wordcount-compilation-errors-related-with-outputcollector-setinputpath-setoutputpath/ .but I dont know xml parsing ...how to start and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a couple of things:

- An input format for processing XML Files, suggest you look at [Mahout's](http://mahout.apache.org/) [XMLInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java)
- A Parser for the XML String passed to the mapper (SAX or DOM), maybe define some JAXB objects to bind to

And some useful links:

- [Parsing XmlInputFormat element larger than hdfs block size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639745/parsing-xmlinputformat-element-larger-than-hdfs-block-size)

Comment: If you're only using XMLFileInputFormat then you could just copy the code into your own codebase and proceed as normal

Comment: @studhadoop if you are not comfortable with Maven for now then you may add all these dependencies by yourself(like include all the jar files manually)

Comment: @studhadoop The same code you reference should be all you need to get the input format working - what are you still having trouble with (be specific)

Comment: You shouldn't need to install Mahout - just copy the XmlInputFormat class to it's own class file in your code base (or if you're using the old mapred api, copy the version from the Mahout link). Then reference it and compile as normal (as if it was part of your code base)

Comment: Just extract the class you need from that file (are you using the new or old api?). Then compile as normal (any reason why you are not using an IDE to make this easier on you?)

Comment: @ChrisWhite: I jst googled (java.dzone.com/articles/hadoop-practice) and tried a sample xml processing map-reduce pgm (github.com/studhadoop/xmlparsing-hadoop/blob/master/…) which should print all the xml contents ,but it is only displaying <configuration></configuration> is there any problem .I am not able to figure out .

Comment: line 179 in your code - you shouldn't swallow exceptions like this, rethrow e as an IOException: `throw new IOException(e);`

Comment: You're still swallowing the exception, you need to re-throw it using the one line of code from my previous comment, and then re-run the program to see what the error is

Comment: @ChrisWhite: yes i re-thrown it ...it is showing Type mismatch in key from map......above is the error..

Comment: You need to output a Text object from your mapper, not a String

Comment: @ChrisWhite: 
ok so where all shid i change

Comment: You've deleted all your previous comments, so i now don't have a link to your current source - repost

Comment: I am sry. https://github.com/studhadoop/xmlparsing-hadoop/blob/master/XmlParser11.java

Comment: line 177: `context.write(new Text(propertyName.trim()), new Text(propertyValue.trim()));`

Comment: now i am trying to work on the desired output. what shld i update in my code.any solution

Comment: Your desired output is very different to what your current implementation does - isn't it a simple case of extracting the text portion of each element and emitting it as the output key of the map, and a LongWritable of 1 as the value, then your reducer is the same as the WordCount reducer?

Comment: @ChrisWhite: is there any way to  visualize my data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916491/visualization-of-xml-data-from-hadoop