# Visualization of xml data from hadoop

Tags: xml, hadoop, hdfs

In my HDFS i will be doing xml processing . ie  processing an xml file and extracting 2 nodes.And this will be my x and y to plot a graph.

How can I do this .Generating graph from hdfs output.I want to use Rapid miner.how can i do this any idea...

OR ELSE

Is there a way to visualize my hadoop data

Comment: the xml file is saved in hdfs?

Comment: yes . they r saved in hdfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way HDFS works is by splitting the file into blocks of predefined size. It just like doing a

```
split -b 64M file.xml
```

And takes each block and saves it to a salve datanode. Now if you HDFS has a block size of 64MB and the file size is 1 GB your file will be split into 16 blocks and saved in different location. So a mapreduce job will not be able to make sense out of a xml file block since xml is structured unlike a simple csv or tsv files. So as far as i can see you cannot process a xml file over hdfs if its greater then the hdfs block size.

Comment: I have several set of x and y values.with this am i able to do visualization in rapidminer and how can it be done??/

Comment: sorry i must still be living in ancient ages, never before heard of xml processing over mapreduce, or any framework doing it.

Comment: https://github.com/studhadoop/xmlparsing-hadoop/blob/master/XmlParser11.java takes the nodes within a specified start and end block